# I2C-dev problem when accessing to ICM20948

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, i2c

I'm configuring a [ICM20948 breakout from primo roni via i2c](https://www.evelta.com/icm20948-9dof-motion-sensor-breakout-i2c/) on a  Beagle Bone black, using a minimal linux build using buildroot, via a C program. To do so, i've [used this driver](https://github.com/mahengunawardena/BeagleboneBlack_I2C_ADXL345) for the i2c connection and also [this ICM20948 driver](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_ICM-20948_ArduinoLibrary) as base for the speciffic device, so the target is to merge both.

I've been able to configure some registers (like the sleepmode o lowpowermode) but when setting the fullscale, the values seems not to be changing.

This is  more or less the function that pressents the problem

```
uint16_t set_values(uint16_t register, uint16_t value)
{
  unsigned char rxBuffer[1];        // receive buffer
  unsigned char txBuffer[2];        // transmit buffer

  retval |= ICM_20948_set_bank(2); // Must be in the right bank
  txBuffer[0] = register;
  retval |= write(device.i2cHandle,txBuffer,1); // device.i2cHandle is the handler obtained when 
  retval |= read(device.i2cHandle,rxBuffer,1);  // opening the /dev/i2c-X
  printf("Readed value %x: %x\n",txBuffer[0],rxBuffer[0]);
  txBuffer[1] = value;
  printf("Intending to write: %x\n", txBuffer[1]);
  retval |= write(device.i2cHandle, txBuffer, sizeof(txBuffer));
  write(device.i2cHandle,txBuffer,1);
  read(device.i2cHandle,rxBuffer,1);
  printf("Written value on register %x: %x\n",txBuffer[0],rxBuffer[0]);
}
```

But the output when doing trying to modify the 0x14 register with the value 0x03 returns what follows:

```
Readed value 14: 1
Intending to write: 3
Written value on register 14: 1
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `retval` is used here to get status of some of your calls, but the code never uses it to verify a good return value before going onto  the next step.  Are you absolutely certain for example that `ICM_20948_set_bank(2);` worked?

Comment: Looking at the datasheet, the device needs SMBus commands to read a register, which cannot be sent using `write` and `read`. The easiest thing to do would be to use `smbus_read_byte_data` to read a register value, and then it would make sense to also use `smbus_write_byte_data` to write a register. These functions are provided by libi2c from i2c-tools.

Comment: Yes, retval is unused. It belongs to the original function, which I simplified and posted here, in order to improve readability. 

ICM_20948_set_bank(2); works fine and other funcions regarding other registers also works fine. This is the strange thing.

 Shall I use libi2c from https://github.com/amaork/libi2c ?

Comment: ADXL345 has its own in-kernel driver, why on earth you are suffering with this ugly approach?

Comment: @Esteban The libi2c from https://github.com/amaork/libi2c should work, although it seems to be mainly an interface for use with Python, so the shared library .so file will be in the wrong place for C development (and besides that, its name would clash with the usual libi2c from i2c-tools).